# How to install second primary DNS on a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dns-zone, windows-server-2019

So I'm testing some features in the windows server 2019 lab. I have one active directory. No need to say that the DNS server is running on the active directory correctly.

I want to add another primary DNS server to the domain but the problem is after installing the DNS role on the second server and configuring the zone with the exact name as the DNS server on the active directory and also configuring zone transfer on both servers, none of them transfer the records to the other one.

What am I missing??

These are the configurations:

1- DC(Active Directory):

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And these are my second server configurations:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the zone replication configured as AD replicated to all DNS servers running on Domain Controllers in the domain. The second server is not a Domain Controller. That's the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what should I do? I can't see any option that says I can replicate with a server that is not a Domain Controler